# handle error when opening .he5 file with python gdal

Tags: python, gdal

I have a .he5 file (xxx.he5). I want to open it with gdal.open(), and get metadata from it with GetMetadata_Dict(). So looks like below:

```
image = gdal.Open("xxx.he5", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
image_attributes = image.GetMetadata_Dict()
```

Then I got the error below (happens at the gdal.Open())

> HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.14.3) thread 0:
> #000: H5Ddeprec.c line 194 in H5Dopen1(): unable to open dataset
> major: Dataset
> minor: Can't open object
> #001: H5VLcallback.c line 1980 in H5VL_dataset_open(): dataset open failed
> major: Virtual Object Layer
> minor: Can't open object
> #002: H5VLcallback.c line 1947 in H5VL__dataset_open(): dataset open failed
> major: Virtual Object Layer
> minor: Can't open object
> #003: H5VLnative_dataset.c line 331 in H5VL__native_dataset_open(): unable to open dataset
> major: Dataset
> minor: Can't open object
> #004: H5Dint.c line 1418 in H5D__open_name(): not found
> major: Dataset
> minor: Object not found
> #005: H5Gloc.c line 421 in H5G_loc_find(): can't find object
> major: Symbol table
> minor: Object not found
> #006: H5Gtraverse.c line 816 in H5G_traverse(): internal path traversal failed
> major: Symbol table
> minor: Object not found
> #007: H5Gtraverse.c line 596 in H5G__traverse_real(): traversal operator failed
> major: Symbol table
> minor: Callback failed
> #008: H5Gloc.c line 381 in H5G__loc_find_cb(): object 'StructMetadata.0' doesn't exist
> major: Symbol table
> minor: Object not found
> ERROR 1: Cannot find StructMetadata.0

But the code still runs through, the GetMetadata_Dict() works fine, and I did obtain the metadata dictionary. But how to avoid this error message?

I have tried to disable it with:

```
gdal.UseExceptions()
gdal.PushErrorHandler('CPLQuietErrorHandler')
```

But not working, still showing the same error.

I tried to use h5py package instead, but the h5py api is completely different, where the the metadata above is not embedded in any group. Any help is appreciated.